# Utilities and apps that bypass Google password/security

Tags: encryption, android

How do applications(UnlockGo) that allow one to connect their Android to PC work in removing password?

I thought the password also is used to encrypt Android device. Is the data erased? i.e. Encrypting and using password still useful even if the pin can be bypassed?

Comment: From [UnlockGo's website](https://itoolab.com/android-phone-unlocker/): *"Unlock screen lock on earlier Samsung devices without data loss (Before S7)."*, which implies that on newer devices, you lose your data. In other words, it's just a factory reset.

Comment: Are you asking about the lock screen, or the (Google's) Factory Reset Protection?